# Power, split plot designs, and mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, experiment-design, statistical-power, nested-data, split-plot

My teammate and I are trying to determine the best way to allocated limited resources (shade cloth and fencing) in an experiment.  We are considering 2 factors: light availability (2 levels) and water availability (3 levels).  For reasons of scale, while water availability is relatively easy and cheap to control, light availability is not.  The latter is about 4 times more costly to establish.  I suggested that we could use a nested split plot design with light availability as the whole plot factor and water availability as the subplot factor, as well as repeatedly sampling the subplots to increase the power of the analysis.  My colleague argued that subsampling would not increase the power and argued instead for simply maximizing the number of true replicates we could do in a complete random design.

So, two questions:

1.) Was I incorrect in my assertion regarding subsampling within a nested design improving power?  I realize these aren't true replicates, but from my understanding, we could account for this in the random effects structure of mixed models.

2.)  If there is a benefit to substantially increasing the number of subplots rather than slightly increasing the number of whole plots, is there any way to evaluate the optimum allocation/number of whole plots and subplots a priori?  It seems power analysis assumes you have some sense of the within and between group variances, but how would that be determined beforehand?

Thanks!